# Does it make sense to bake your AMI if you use cfn-init in your cloudformation template?

Tags: bootstrapping, aws-cloudformation

I am starting to doubt if I might be missing the whole point of cfn-init. I started thinking that I should bake my AMI used in my cfn template to save time so it doesn't waste time reinstalling all the packages so I can quickly test the next boostrapping steps. But if I have in my cfn-init commands to download awslogs and stream my logs by executing the cfn-init command in my userdata, if I bake that in, my log group will be created, but doesn't the awslog program need to run a fresh command to start streaming logs, it just does not make sense if that command is baked in. Which brings me to my next question, is cfn-init bootstrapping designed (or at least best practice) to run it everytime a new ec2 is spun up, i.e. you cannot or should not bake in the cfn-init part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your doubt is very valid and it is purely the design approach and style of working of the devop.

If your cfn-int just accomplishes installing few packages; very well this can be baked in the AMI. As you rightly pointed it would save time and ensure faster stack creation.

However what if you would like to install the latest version of the packages; in That case you can just add the latest flag / keyword to the cfn-init package section. I have used the cfn-init to dynamically to accept the BIOS name of the Active Directory - Domain Controller; so in this case I wouldn't be able to bake that in AMI.

Another place where cfn-init helps is that assume that you have configured 4 packages to be installed; what if you there is a requirement of yet another package to be also installed; in that case - If it is CloudFormation cfn-init - it is another single line of code to be added. If it is AMI - a new AMI approach new AMI has to Baked.

This is purely a trade off.